# Linux Kernel Code Execution Contexts

Tags: process, linux-kernel

When a process executing in the user space issues a `system call` or triggers an `exception`, it enters into the kernel space and kernel starts executing on behalf of the process. Kernel is said to be executing in the `process context`. Similarly when an interrupt occurs kernel executes in the `interrupt context`. I have studied about kernel execution in `kernel thread`, where kernel processes runs in the background.

My Questions are :

1. Does the kernel execute in any other contexts?
2. Suppose a process in the user space never executes a system call or triggers an exception or no interrupt occurs, does the kernel code ever execute ?

Comment: I don't think there can exist a process which never executes a system call.

Comment: Agreed. I suppose then only the contexts i mentioned in my question exists where the kernel code runs ?

Comment: @balki: `for(;;) __asm__ __volatile__("nop");`

Comment: There is also NMI context, but you can pretty much ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

The kernel runs periodically, it sets a timer to fire an interrupt at some predefined frequency (100 Hz (Linux 2.4/x86), 1000Hz (early Linux 2.6/x86), 250Hz (newer Linux 2.6/x86)).

The kernel need to do this in order to do preemptive multitasking. OTOH, OSes only doing cooperative multitasking (Windows 3.1, classic Mac OS) needn't do this, and only switch tasks on response to some call from the running task (which could lead to runaway tasks hanging the whole system).

Note that there is some effort to optimize the use of this timer: newer Linux is smarter when there are no runnable tasks, it sets the timer as far in the future as it can, to allow the CPU to sleep longer and deeper, and preserve power (the `CONFIG_NOHZ` kernel config option). Running `powertop` will show the number of wakeups per second, which on an idle system can be much lower than the 250 wakeups per second you'd expect of a traditional implementation.

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose a process in the user space never executes a system call or triggers an exception or no interrupt occurs, does the kernel code ever execute ?

Assume you have a process `p` that is running the following code: `while(1);`. This code will never call into the kernel and won't cause any faults. (It *might* have set an `alarm(3)` earlier, causing a signal to be delivered in the future, or it might exceed the `setrlimit(2)` CPU limit, in which cases the kernel will deliver a signal to the process.)

Or, if another process sends `p` a signal via `kill(2)`, the kernel will deliver that signal to the process as well.

The signal delivery will either cause a signal handler to run, do nothing (if the signal is ignored or masked), or take the default signal action (which might be nothing or termination).

And, of course, the process execution can be interrupted so the processor can handle interrupts; or a higher-priority process can preempt it.

Comment: This is not true on single CPU core systems. How is the kernel going to run if there are no interrupts, system calls or exceptions? And if it cannot run then there will be no alarms, cpu limit checking or other processes running. Of course the fact is that on linux a process cannot stop some interrupts (e.g. timer) and on SMP systems other processes can run on other threads.

Comment: @Dipstick, obviously, if you defeat the kernel's normal 'tick' mechanism, it'll stop working as advertised. :)

Comment: Hmmm. Just noticed that my above comment doesn't entirely make sense - but the gist of it is about right.